# Control name of returned types in Spring Data REST Query

Tags: java, rest, jackson, spring-data-mongodb, spring-data-rest

Is it possible to control the class name used when returning search results in Spring Data REST?

I have a class `Account` which is published as a JSON schema and does not include an `id` field, as that should be opaque in a RESTful API. In order to persist this using Spring Data MongoDB, I extend `Account` with `PersistableAccount` which has an `id` field.

When returning search results to the client, the name `persistableAccounts` is exposed, which is an implementation detail that should not leak into the API:

```
{
  "_embedded" : {
    "persistableAccounts" : [ {
      "lastName" : "McLastName",
      "firstName" : "Kevin",
      "phoneNumber " : "+44 7700000000",
      "email" : "kevin@example.com",
      "_links" : {
        "self" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:64712/accounts/id"
        },
        "persistableAccount" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:64712/accounts/id"
        }
      }
    } ]
  },
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:64712/accounts/search/findByFirstName?firstName=Kevin"
    }
  }
}
```

Is it possible to control the term used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring Data Rest always includes a *collectionRel* in the reponse if your result may consist of multiple subtypes.

By default it is the class name, however, you can customize it within `@RepositoryRestResource` annotation on your repository.

For example:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "whateverIwantHere")
public interface CustomerRepository extends CrudRepository<Customer, Long> {

}
```

Comment: Thanks! I figured it would take its name from that of the repository, rather than one of the generic types.